# D3 : Unable to get property 'weight' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

D3 svg is graph stops working when I assign link.source and link.target to integer values retrieved from DB. If I assign index starting with 0 graph works fine, but it fails with above error when I assign link.source and .target with identifier values retrieved from db.

Comment: I think we're going to need an [mcve] here.

Answer (score -2):

```
var edges = [];
json.Links.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.Id === e.Source;
      })[0],
      targetNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.Id === e.Target;
      })[0];

  edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: e.Value
  });
});

force
  .nodes(json.Nodes)
  .links(edges)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
   .data(edges)
```

Comment: Really? This is not supposed to be an answer, is it?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.